# DatabaseSessionIsOver with Pony ORM due to lazy loading?

Tags: python, orm, ponyorm

I am using Pony ORM for a flask solution and I've come across the following.

Consider the following:

```
@db_session
def get_orders_of_the_week(self, user, date):
    q = select(o for o in Order for s in o.supplier if o.user == user)
    q2 = q.filter(lambda o: o.date >= date and o.date <= date+timedelta(days=7))
    res = q2[:]

    #for r in res:
    #    print r.supplier.name

    return res
```

When I need the result in Jinja2 -- which is looks like this

```
{% for order in res %}
    Supplier: {{ order.supplier.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

I get a

```
DatabaseSessionIsOver: Cannot load attribute Supplier[3].name: the database session is over
```

If I uncomment the `for r in res` part, it works fine. I suspect there is some sort of lazy loading that doesn't get loaded with `res = q2[:]`.
Am I completely missing a point or what's going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you're trying to access the related object which was not loaded and since you're trying to access it outside of the database session (the function decorated with the `db_session`), Pony raises this exception.

The recommended approach is to use the `db_session` decorator at the top level, at the same place where you put the Flask's `app.route` decorator:

```
@app.route('/index')
@db_session
def index():
    ....
    return render_template(...)
```

This way all calls to the database will be wrapped with the database session, which will be finished after a web page is generated.

If there is a reason that you want to narrow the database session to a single function, then you need to iterate the returning objects inside the function decorated with the `db_session` and access all the necessary related objects. Pony will use the most effective way for loading the related objects from the database, avoiding the N+1 Query problem. This way Pony will extract all the necessary objects within the `db_session` scope, while the connection to the database is still active.

--- update:

Right now, for loading the related objects, you should iterate over the query result and call the related object attribute:

```
for r in res:
    r.supplier.name
```

It is similar to the code in your example, I just removed the `print` statement. When you 'touch' the `r.supplier.name` attribute, Pony loads all non-lazy attributes of the related `supplier` object. If you need to load lazy attributes, you need to touch each of them separately.

Seems that we need to introduce a way to specify what related objects should be loaded during the query execution. We will add this feature in one of the future releases.

Comment: In my case, the method decorated with `db_session` is in a repository module, and having a decorator `db_session` outside this repository defeats its purpose (by increasing the coupling between the route function and the repo implementation). Is there a more elegant way of iterating through all returning objects than what I've attempted to do? I would like all data from all sub-objects available one the method return its result.

Comment: That sounds great! I the mean time I'll 'touch' where needed. I was mislead by the `[:]` as I thought it would freeze everything in the query to a list.

Comment: The consequence of applying the slice syntax `[:]` is that Pony sends the query to the database, constructs objects based on the extracted rows and puts them into a resulting list. The list consists of entity instances.

Here you can find a bit more information about it: http://doc.ponyorm.com/working_with_entity_instances.html#getting-several-objects

Answer (score 7):

I just added prefetch functionality that should solve your problem. You can take working code from the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ponyorm/pony). This feature will be part of the upcoming release Pony ORM 0.5.4.

Now you can write:

```
q = q.prefetch(Supplier)
```

or

```
q = q.prefetch(Order.supplier)
```

and Pony will automatically load related `supplier` objects.

Below I'll show several queries with prefetching, using the standard Pony example with Students, Groups and Departments.

```
from pony.orm.examples.presentation import *
```

Loading Student objects only, without any prefetching:

```
students = select(s for s in Student)[:]
```

Loading students together with groups and departments:

```
students = select(s for s in Student).prefetch(Group, Department)[:]

for s in students: # no additional query to the DB is required
    print s.name, s.group.major, s.group.dept.name
```

The same as above, but specifying attributes instead of entities:

```
students = select(s for s in Student).prefetch(Student.group, Group.dept)[:]

for s in students: # no additional query to the DB is required
    print s.name, s.group.major, s.group.dept.name
```

Loading students and its courses (many-to-many relationship):

```
students = select(s for s in Student).prefetch(Student.courses)

for s in students:
    print s.name
    for c in s.courses: # no additional query to the DB is required
        print c.name
```

As a parameters of the `prefetch()` method you can specify entities and/or attributes. If you specified an entity, then all *to-one* attributes with this type will be prefetched. If you specified an attribute, then this specific attribute will be prefetched. The to-many attributes are prefetched only when specified explicitly (as in the `Student.courses` example). The prefetching goes recursively, so you can load long chain of attributes, such as `student.group.dept`.

When object is prefetched, then by default all of its attributes are loaded, except lazy attributes and to-many attributes. You can prefetch lazy and to-many attributes explicitly if it is needed.

I hope this new method fully covers your use-case. If something is not working as expected, please [start new issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/issues/new). Also you can discuss functionality and make feature requests at [Pony ORM mailing list](http://ponyorm-list.ponyorm.com).

P.S. I'm not sure that repository pattern that you use give your serious benefits. I think that it actually increase coupling between template rendering and repo implementation, because you may need to change repo implementation (i.e. add new entities to prefetching list) when template code start using of new attributes. With the top-level `@db_session` decorator you can just send query result to the template and all happens automatically, without the need of explicit prefetching. But maybe I'm missing something, so I will be interested to see additional comments about the benefits of using the repository pattern in your case.

Comment: This is great! I will be employing the `prefetch` a lot. The repository is a way to abstract away Pony. It was mostly in the beginning of my project where I didn't know whether or not to employ Pony or something else. With my increasing Pony riding skills and your continuous development efforts, the need for a repository does indeed seem to vanish as the queries become so pythonic it makes little sense to hide them in a repo.